# Get Row Count in MultiPage Gridview?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, label, datasource, rowcount

when i try to do the following:

```
lblTotal.text  = gwGrid.rows.count()
```

i always get 50, which is the size of my page. how can i get the count of ALL records returned, not just the ones displayed on that one page?

i also tried the Selected event on my datasource:

```
Protected Sub ObjectDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

    If e.Exception Is Nothing AndAlso e.ReturnValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(e.ReturnValue, DataTable)
        Dim totalRecordCount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
    End If

End Sub
```

but i get the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on this line: 
Line 85:             `Dim totalRecordCount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count`

udpate: i figure it out:

```
 Protected Sub ObjectDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
        If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataSet = DirectCast(e.ReturnValue, DataSet)
            If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                lblTotal.Text = dt.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString()
            Else
                lblTotal.Text = "0"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub ObjectDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
        If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataSet = DirectCast(e.ReturnValue, DataSet)
            If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                lblTotal.Text = dt.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString()
            Else
                lblTotal.Text = "0"
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the answer for this question using an SqlDataSource, use the same event, but just use e.AffectedRows for your count.

```
Protected Sub WorkerData_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles WorkerData.Selected

    If e.Exception Is Nothing Then

        Dim rows As Integer = e.AffectedRows

        'AddMessage(rows.ToString & " Workers selected", UpdateMessage)

    End If

End Sub
```

That worked perfectly for me.